# How to create a reference to a specific user with firebase-collection?

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.1 with firebase-collection element.

I want to retrieve a specific user's information in my database and the structure is as follows:

```
<userId>
 - name: "joe"
 - email: "provider"
 - fullName: "Joe Brown"
```

My firebase collection works but I get all user's information:

```
<firebase-collection
      limit-to-first="1"
      location="https://storklancer.firebaseio.com/users/"
      data="{{users}}"></firebase-collection>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]" as="user">
       <span>Name: </span><span>[[user.fullName]]</span>
      </template>
```

If I put `limit-to-first="3"` I get all information but I need the information from a specific user. Assume this user has an id of 1234:

```
<firebase-collection
      limit-to-first="1"
      location="https://storklancer.firebaseio.com/users/1234" // I thought that would work
      data="{{users}}"></firebase-collection>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]" as="user">
       <span>Name: </span><span>[[user.fullName]]</span>
      </template>
```

I need to return user 1234's `fullName`. Is it possible with the firebase-collection element or it's only done the [firebase way](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a firebase-document element instead with location set to the path of the user & data will be the full user's info.

Update with code:

```
<firebase-document
      location="https://storklancer.firebaseio.com/users/1234"
      data="{{user}}"></firebase-document>
```

Then in your element's DOM something like:

```
<span>Name: </span><span>[[user.fullName]]</span>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Im struggling to know how to use it. Their demo shows nothing useful.

Comment: No worries - I've added some code, hopefully that helps, if not let me know.

Comment: Thanks. My data is `users` and your answer works perfectly. Funny....I could assume I was doing the same. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it helped :)